# How can change start up in Office 2010 Automation C# Application

Tags: c#, office-interop, excel-2010, office-automation

I'm trying to create new Office excel workbook application how can i change start-up of this application to start with windows form instead of opening excel.

Thanks
[image: Like This]

Comment: why wouldnt you create a winform application and then automate excel from there?

Comment: No problem but i think this will gave me full functionality of Excel if you suggestions please tell me 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to edit a workbook in a GUI created in windows forms? Or just double clicking the excel to open the application you created?

Comment: Create workbooks , fill ,edit from windows forms.

Comment: Then you need to seach for a component that does the job... try googling something like "component to edit excel"

Comment: Thanks 
Please if you have any tutorial for Office Automation put link here
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

1. Create two projects under your solution, one a winforms (or whatever it is), the other 
   excel workbook application.
2. Set Winforms application as your startup project.
3. Reference excel application project to your winforms project.
4. Open up Excel application from your code in winforms project when required. Like this or so:

   ```
   using (Process excelProcess = new Process())
   {
       excelProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SomeClassInExcelApplicationProject)).Location;
       excelProcess.Start();
   }
   ```

   If you want winforms to close upon starting excel application, add `Application.Exit();` after starting excel application process